# search_after giving wrong result with backward pagination in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

With elasticsearch, I am trying to implement pagination with the help of search_after. I am getting an issue when I am doing backward pagination, ie. wrong result (Differs from actual results from the previous page).

For forward pagination, I am using elastic query as follows...

```
{
"sort": [{
    "_score": "desc"
}, {
    "last_login": {
        "order": "desc",
        "mode": "avg"
    }
}, {
    "id": {
        "order": "asc"
    }
}],
"search_after": [148853, 1563037185, "3591152"],
"from": 0,
"_source": [],
"track_total_hits": true,
"track_scores": true,
"aggs": {},
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [],
                "must_not": [],
                "must": []
            }
        },
        "should": [],
        "must_not": [],
        "must": []
    }
},
"size": 25
```

}

Note: Here search_after value is the sort array of the last document from the current pagination.

For doing reverse pagination,

I am just reversing the sort order of the sorting options as mentioned in the thread [elastic discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-get-a-previous-page-from-elasticsearch-using-search-after/105028/2).
My elastic query is now as follows...

```
{
"sort": [{
    "_score": "asc"
}, {
    "last_login": {
        "order": "asc",
        "mode": "avg"
    }
}, {
    "id": {
        "order": "desc"
    }
}],
"search_after": [146923, 1561460886, "3275906"],
"from": 0,
"_source": [],
"track_total_hits": true,
"track_scores": true,
"aggs": {},
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [],
                "must_not": [],
                "must": []
            }
        },
        "should": [],
        "must_not": [],
        "must": []
    }
},
"size": 25
```

}

Here search_after is the value from the sort array of the last document in the current pagination.
This time instead of showing previous page results, elastic gives some other results.

Note: Elasticsearch version 7.2

**NB: There is no realtime update or indexing happening to the elasticsearch.**

**UPDATE:** If I give the first document from the current page and reverse  the elasticsearch result, then I will get the previous page (Without using _score as a sort param).
But when sorting enabled based on the score I am getting again a completely wrong result.

Comment: Your update confuses me a little. Are you using just score as sorting category then? If so, elastic tiebreaks different scores with a tiebreaking function that might not always return the same order, especially if you have multiple nodes.

Comment: @StefanoBranco. I am using score with other sorting parameters. Even I am using one ID also which is unique across all the documents.